DNS resolve a web address to a domain other then the one your are on
I am on a domain called MySite.local. I have a web address workforce.com that resolves to 74.6.143.25. I want my local hosts on Mysite.local to resolve workforce.com to 10.10.10.10
When I try create a Cname is sets the FQDN of the record to workforce.com.Mysite.Local.
Is a Cname record the wrong way to do this?
Is this possible?

The record type does not matter at this stage. All DNS records follow the same naming rules, and the problem is that a DNS zone cannot have "out-of-zone" names – if you have a mysite.local DNS zone, then it can only contain .mysite.local records (domains/subdomains) in general, whether they are CNAME or not.
You could either create a second DNS zone (primary) named workforce.com to override that entire domain, then define a regular A record there (i.e. A 10.10.10.10); or you could use the DNS server's custom override features – which Windows Server DNS does not have, as far as I know (but e.g. BIND9 does and so does Unbound, so you could point your hosts to an Unbound resolver with this override).
